# C++: Dungeon Crawler - Issue when updating array

Tags: c++

I'm working on a Dungeon Crawler for my C++ class, and have run into an issue with updating/displaying the array element representing my character. The 'up', 'left', and 'right' functionalities work normally (IE, array element corresponding to x/y position is increased or decreased by 1 and displays the update accurately), but the 'down' movement causes the character to disappear. I've tried changing the character, removing the code that overwrites the old position, and a couple other things to determine exactly what is happening to no avail. Any feedback is much appreciated (note that the checkWin function is not complete).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

const int max_row = 10;
const int max_col = 10;
const char character = 'O', treasure = 'X', traps = 'T', space = '.';

void showInstructions();
void createDungeon(char dungeon[max_row][max_col], int max_col);
void displayDungeon(char dungeon[max_row][max_col], int max_col);
void getMove(char& movement, char dungeon[max_row][max_col],int max_col);
void checkMove(char& movement, char dungeon[max_row][max_col], int max_col);
void updateDungeon(char& movement, char dungeon[max_row][max_col], int max_col);
int checkCharPositionY(char dungeon[max_row][max_col], int max_col);
int checkCharPositionX(char dungeon[max_row][max_col], int max_col);
void checkWin (char dungeon[max_row][max_col], int max_col, bool& playing);
string getDirection(char movement);


int main()
{

    bool playing = true;
    int character_pos, trap_pos[3], treasure_pos;
    char movement;

    char dungeon[max_row][max_col] = {{'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                                      {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                                      {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                                      {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                                      {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                                      {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                                      {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                                      {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                                      {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                                      {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'}};

    showInstructions();
    createDungeon(dungeon, max_col);

    while (playing) {

    displayDungeon(dungeon, max_col);
    getMove(movement, dungeon, max_col);
    checkMove(movement, dungeon, max_col);
    updateDungeon(movement, dungeon, max_col);
    checkWin(dungeon, max_col, playing);

    }

}

void createDungeon(char dungeon[][max_col], int max_col) {

    int trap_count = 0, srand(time(0));

    dungeon[0][0] = character;

    while(trap_count < 3) {

        if(dungeon[rand() % 10][rand() % 10] == space) {

            dungeon[rand() % 10][rand() % 10] = traps;
            trap_count++;

        }

    }

    if (dungeon[rand() % 10][rand() % 10] == space) {
        dungeon[rand() % 10][rand() % 10] = treasure;

    }

}

void showInstructions() {

    cout << "Hello and welcome to your doom! Whether by fate or fiat, you have entered the \n";
    cout << "dungeon. To win, make your way to the treasure. If you find a trap, you will \n";
    cout << "instead find death. With treasure comes release and fortune. Your character is \n";
    cout << "represented with 'O', traps with 'T', and the treasure with 'X'. You will always";
    cout << "begin in the upper left hand corner of the maze. Good luck - you'll need it. \n";
    cout << "\nTo navigate the dungeon, use the 'W','A','S', and 'D' keys as shown below:\n\n";
    cout << setw(39) << "^\n";
    cout << setw(40) << "[W]\n";
    cout << setw(46) << " < [A]   [S] > \n";
    cout << setw(40) << " [D]\n";
    cout << setw(39) << "v\n";

}

void displayDungeon(char dungeon[max_row][max_col], int max_col) {

    for(int row = 0; row < max_col; row++) {
        cout << endl;
        cout << setw(23);
        for(int col = 0; col < max_col; col++) {
            cout << " " << dungeon[row][col] << " ";
        }
    }
}

void getMove(char& movement, char dungeon[max_row][max_col], int max_col) {

    cout << "\n\nPick a direction for your character to move.\n";
    cin >> movement;

    while (movement != 'w' && movement != 'a' && movement != 's' && movement != 'd' &&
           movement != 'W' && movement != 'A' && movement != 'S' && movement != 'D'    ) {

        cin.clear();
        cout << "That was not a valid selection. Please navigate using W, A, S, or D.\n";
        cin >> movement;

    }

    if (movement == 'w') {
        movement = 'W';
    }
    else if (movement == 'a') {
        movement = 'A';
    }
    else if (movement == 's') {
        movement = 'S';
    }
    else if (movement == 'd') {
        movement = 'D';
    }

}

void checkMove(char& movement, char dungeon[max_row][max_col], int max_col) {

    while (movement == 'W' && checkCharPositionY(dungeon, max_col) == 0) {
        cin.clear();
        cout << "\nYou cannot exit the dungeon that way! Try again. \n";
        getMove(movement, dungeon, max_col);
    }

    while (movement == 'S' && checkCharPositionY(dungeon, max_col) == 9) {
        cin.clear();
        cout << "\nYou cannot exit the dungeon that way! Try again. \n";
        getMove(movement, dungeon, max_col);
    }

    while (movement == 'A' && checkCharPositionX(dungeon, max_col) == 0) {
        cin.clear();
        cout << "\nYou cannot exit the dungeon that way! Try again. \n";
        getMove(movement, dungeon, max_col);
    }

    while (movement == 'D' && checkCharPositionX(dungeon, max_col) == 9) {
        cin.clear();
        cout << "\nYou cannot exit the dungeon that way! Try again. \n";
        getMove(movement, dungeon, max_col);
    }

    cout << "You moved " << getDirection(movement) << endl;

}

void updateDungeon(char& movement, char dungeon[max_row][max_col], int max_col) {

    switch (movement) {
        case 'W':
            for (int i = 0; i < max_col; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < max_col; j++) {
                    if (dungeon[i][j] == 'O') {
                        dungeon[i][j] = '.';
                        dungeon[i - 1][j] = 'O';
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case 'A':
            for (int i = 0; i < max_col; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < max_col; j++) {
                    if (dungeon[i][j] == 'O') {
                        dungeon[i][j] = '.';
                        dungeon[i][j - 1] = 'O';
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case 'S':
            for (int i = 0; i < max_col; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < max_col; j++) {
                    if (dungeon[i][j] == 'O') {
                        dungeon[i+1][j] = 'O';
                        dungeon[i][j] = '.';
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        case 'D':
            for (int i = 0; i < max_col; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < max_col; j++) {
                    if (dungeon[i][j] == 'O') {
                        dungeon[i][j] = '.';
                        dungeon[i][j + 1] = 'O';
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}

string getDirection(char movement) {

    string direction;

    if (movement == 'W' || movement == 'w') {
        direction = "up.";
    }
    else if (movement == 'A' || movement == 'a') {
        direction = "left.";
    }
    else if (movement == 'D' || movement == 'd') {
        direction = "right.";
    }
    else if (movement == 'S' || movement == 's') {
        direction = "down.";
    }

    return direction;
}

int checkCharPositionY(char dungeon[max_row][max_col], int max_col) {

    for (int row = 0; row < max_col; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < max_col; col++) {
                if (dungeon[row][col] == 'O') {
                    return row;
                }

            }
    }

}

int checkCharPositionX(char dungeon[max_row][max_col], int max_col) {

    for (int row = 0; row < max_col; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < max_col; col++) {
                if (dungeon[row][col] == 'O') {
                    return col;
                }

            }
    }

}

void checkWin (char dungeon[max_row][max_col], int max_col, bool& playing) {

    int treasurepos[max_row][max_col], trappos[max_row][max_col];

    for (int i = 0; i < max_col; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < max_col; j++) {
                if (dungeon[i][j] == 'X') {
                    treasurepos[i][j] = dungeon[i][j];
                }

            }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < max_col; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < max_col; j++) {
                if (dungeon[i][j] == 'T') {
                    trappos[i][j] = dungeon[i][j];
                }

            }
    }



}
```

Edit: The issue appears tied to the fact it's not exiting the loop despite the break statement. Traps will spawn in index 0 and be overwritten if I try to move down. Chaning the '.' character to @ or another character will show that it's writing it all the way through index 0.

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is that you're not breaking out of your loop once you find the right position. So for the `S` case in `updatedDungeon()`, you move the `O` over 1 position when you find it. On the next time through the loop, you find the `O` again, and move it again. On the next time through the loop, you find the `O` again and move it again. etc. You need to stop looping as soon as you've found and moved the character.

Another, possibly better, way to move the character might be to keep its position in a separate variable, update that variable, and redraw the board with the new information.

Comment: I think you're right, i'm just a bit flabbergasted that it's only happening in the 'S' case and not the others. I'll continue tooling around, but I think recording the positions separately is exactly what I need to do. And no worries, I appreciate the insight.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you propose stopping the loop and exiting the case (without using a goto)?

Comment: Instead of the `break` inside the `if`, you could simply have a `return` statement. A better way might be to have an additional condition on the loops. Something like `for (i = 0; (i < max_col) && (!found); i++)` and then set `found` to true once you've found the player's position.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, I appreciate your help!